# Lack of transparency in beamer default theme

Tags: beamer, transparency

I'm using the default LaTeX beamer theme. Unfortunately, for some reason, I don't get transparency anymore. The behaviour is the same across pdflatex, xelatex and lualatex.

Rendered:

[image: No transparency]

MWE (requires an arbitrary image file):

```
\documentclass[compress,xcolor={usenames,dvipsnames,table},12pt]{beamer}

\title{Title}
\author{Author}
\date{September 14th, 2018}

\setbeamertemplate{background}{%
  \includegraphics[width=\paperwidth,height=\paperheight]{background.jpg}
}


\begin{document}

  \begin{frame}
    \titlepage
  \end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Is the image really produced with the exact same code you show in the question? per default, blocks on the title page are not coloured. If some other theme would be used, the image can be reproduced.

Comment: Can you add which version of beamer you have? I vaguely remember that there might have been a bug a couple of month ago.

Comment: I flagged the question as duplicate. I found the solution myself: it's indeed a bug in some beamer versions.